# Regular Expression not Matching Entire Input Text as Expected

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have the following regular expression:

```
(=)(?<!\\\\)(')(.*?)(?<!\\\\)(')(.*?)
```

Which should match an equal sign followed by any set of characters between single quotes and then anything that comes after.

But when I test it with the sample text `='abc'xyz`, it only matches `='abc'`.

I also tested the code here: https://regexr.com/61gof

Any ideas as to why that is?

Comment: You can simply rewrite your rule as /\B=\'\w+\'\w+/gm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `?` makes the last `(.*?)` to match lazily, so matching as few character as possible, which will be 0. Remove the `?` or put a `$` at the end of the regex telling it it should match until the end of the line (if that is what you want).